# Trying to increment Y in this single line loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, increment

I need to increment Y so that when Y is added to the values in the array it adds 1 then 2 then 3.

Tried to run a loop above the single line one but im having issues and for some reason adding values within the list is finicky for me.

```
answer = [5,8,13,16]
y=0
new_arr = [y+x for x in answer]
```

Expected output

```
new_arr = [5, 9, 15, 19]
```

Comment: Example? expected output?

Comment: Expected output added to it

Comment: `[y+x for y,x in enumerate(answer)]` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate` runs an index along with the iteration values:

```
answer = [5,8,13,16]
new_arr = [y+x for y, x in enumerate(answer)]
```

Output:

```
[5, 9, 15, 19]
```

Comment: this is very nice.

Comment: knew it had to be something simple that I couldnt find! thank you so much

Comment: can even get rid of the `y = 0` since we actually replace the value in y with the index from the enumerate

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make `y` an regular number, try making it a list with the values `[0, 1, 2, 3...]` and adding it to the original list.

The following code should do what you want:

```py
# The input
x = [5,8,13,16]

# An array containing [0, 1, 2, 3, ... len(x) - 1 ] with the exact size of the input
y = range(len(x))

# Iterate on both arrays, adding entries one by one
answer = [(z[0] + z[1]) for z in zip(x, y)]

print(answer)
```

Output:

```
[5, 9, 15, 19]
```

---

As a bonus, for that solution, with `numpy` and [np.arrange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), you get a really readable code that most python programmers would understand:

```py
import numpy as np

x = [5,8,13,16]
y = np.arange(len(x))
answer = x + y

print(answer)
```

Output:

```
[5 9 15 19]
```

Comment: Nice use of generator from range. computationally would it be faster to to `z[0] + z[1]` rather than call to `sum()`

Comment: I have added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two good answers so far but adding a third just for variety, bit more expensive as loads a module and calls next method. but adding none the less as another option.

```
from itertools import count
answer = [5,8,13,16]
y=count(0)
new = [x + next(y) for x in answer]
print(new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[5, 9, 15, 19]
```